# Im having Trouble with Parlai blenderbot on google collab

Tags: python, github, parlai, blenderbot

I am having difficulty running blenderbot on google collab.  Is this a good platform to use this code on?  What else will need to be installed on my device?

Comment: Please provide more details about the difficulties you are having so people can help you.

Comment: For some reason this piece of code will not run on google colab - cd ~/ParlAI; python setup.py develop